# How to use all of the flash memory on an embedded unix system

Tags: python, bash

I want to stress test the flash memory in an embedded Ubuntu system. For example, create files and store in the flash memory until there is no room. Is there a straight forward way of accomplishing this? I'm thinking that bash or a python script would be instrumental in testing this? Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My favorite way of doing this is redirecting the output from the [`yes`](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man1/yes.1.php) command to a file.

```
 $ yes > /path/to/my/device/yes.txt
```

You can limit it by using `head`:

```
 $ yes | head -n1000000 > /path/to/my/device/yes.txt
```

A bit more of an explanation. `yes` will continuously output the letter "y" followed by a newline... forever. When you redirect this output to a file, it will continue to add to that file until space runs out on the disk (or in some file systems, the max file size is reached).

Comment: can your explain what is happening when executing this command?

Comment: I added some more explanation. Basically, it writes to yes.txt the letter 'y' infinitely.